# NSRegularExpression giving warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, xcode, nsregularexpression

Here is the code

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

The code itself works but gives this warning:

```
"Unknown escape sequence \."
```

I also tried the options:

```
NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines
```

but still the error persists. Can anyone explain why this error comes up and how it can be removed.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812206/unknown-escape-sequence-regular-expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write your regular expression as a string literal and it contains backslashes, you have to escape them using a second backslash because the backslash is also used for escaping some special characters (e.g. `\n`, `\t` etc.) in strings literals.

So if you want your regular expression to contain `\.`, you have to write it as `\\.`. Again, this only applies if you use string literals, not if you would load your regex from file.

If you actually want to have a period without a backslash (which is effectively what you have now), remove the backslash to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Yes, it makes the dot a literal dot in the regex, as opposed to being part of the regex syntax. I would guess that this is how the regex is supposed to be used. Otherwise, you'd have to remove the backslashes to get identical behavior without the warning.

Comment: @omz: I think it's not going to change the meaning in this case. The warning looks like it came from the string processor, not the regex engine. This means that it was implicitly translated into `\\.`. But it's still a useful warning because some other escape sequences like `\b` (backspace vs. word boundary) do change their meaning if they are not escaped properly.

Comment: I just did a little test; `[@"foo\.bar" isEqualToString:@"foo.bar"]` returns `YES`, so the backslash in `\.` is simply ignored and not implicitly translated to a double backslash.

Comment: omz is totally right... removing the "\" does give me the same behavior as opposed to double slash "\\."... thanks a lot

Comment: please correct the answer @omz.. and change it to "." instead of typing "\\." because in context of question, a NSString is involved. :)